# c# 10 textbox to display array items, 30 lines in each textbox, separated with comma

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string

I have 10 different textbox control and a textfile upload script on a button click. I want that when a user uploads a textfile which probably will consist 300 lines, it gets divided into 10 different textbox, 30 lines in each textbox, where each line separated with comma. I have used array to store textfile items.

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Text file";
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
                button9.Text = textBox13.Text.ToString();
                textBox1.Text = string.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, text.Take(30));
                if (text.Length >  30)
                    textBox2.Text = string.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, text[0]);
        }
}
```

Comment: And the question is ... ?

Comment: how will I be able to display textfile items into 10 different textbox, each textbox containing 30 lines from textfile seperated with comma. @Lasse V. Karlsen

Comment: So your question is really how to take a text file which consists of many/multiple lines, dividing that up into sections of 30 (lines) each, and then assigning each section to its own text box?

Comment: Yes exactly @Lasse V. Karlsen dividing textfile in 30 and assigning each section to textbox

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? It seems that ReadAllLines returns a string array (assuming your code is correct). You can iterate through the array and put 30 lines into a string and so on. If you get stuck you can ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code you can use for that, an explanation follows:

```
string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
var thirtyLineSections = text
    .Select((line, index) => new { line, group = index / 30 })
    .GroupBy(item => item.group)
    .ToArray();
int textboxIndex = 0;
foreach (var section in thirtyLineSections)
{
    string textForSection = string.Join(",",
        section.Select(item => item.line).ToArray()); // see note below
    textboxes[textboxIndex].Text = textForSection;
    textboxIndex++;
}
```

Note: If you're using .NET 4.0 or above you can remove the call to `.ToArray()`, and instead use this line for the one with the comment:

```
section.Select(item => item.line));
```

So, what will this code do?

First, it'll take each line from the original file and run that through a `.Select(...)` method. This method will be given a 0-based index and the actual element (line) from the original collection. In other words, the delegate to the Select method will be passed the value 0,"first line", 1,"second line", 2,"third line", and so on. We divide this by 30 to get a "group number", where the first group will be number 0, and so on. Then we group on that group number to put all the lines with the same group number into the same group.

In other words, you got this:

```
original file     with index          after dividing by 30
line 1            0,line 1            0,line 1
line 2            1,line 2            0,line 2
line 3            2,line 3            0,line 3
some text         3,some text         0,some text
line 5            4,line 5            0,line 5
...
line 30           29,line 30          0,line 30
line 31           30,line 31          1,line 31
```

So out of that LINQ query we will get an array of elements, where each element is a group that contains 30 lines of text from the original file, in the order they occured in.

Then we loop on that array, handling 30 elements at a time, and combining them into one string using `string.Join`, assigning the result to a textbox.

Before executing this code you need to do this:

```
var textboxes = new[]
{
    textbox1,
    textbox2,
    ...
    textboxN
};
```

to create an array of the textboxes you want to assign those strings to.

Note: This code does not ensure that you have enough textboxes. If you've dropped 10 textboxes on the form, capable of handling 300 elements, and got more than 300 lines in that file, the code will throw an exception.

---

OK, as was pointed out in a comment, the LINQ query "looks good", but may be hard to understand for new programmers. I totally agree, so here is a different way to accomplish the same thing:

```
string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
var thirtyLineSections = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> currentList = null;
foreach (string line in text)
{
    if (currentList == null)
    {
        currentList = new List<string>();
        thirtyLineSections.Add(currentList);
    }
    currentList.Add(line);
    if (currentList.Count == 30)
        currentList = null;
}

foreach (var section in thirtyLineSections)
{
    string.Join(",", section).Dump();
}
```

So what will this code do?

First it'll create the data structure, which in this case will be a "list of 30-line lists", ie. the `List<List<string>>` declaration.

Then it will loop through all the lines in the file. For each line it will check if we're currently in a group, and we start as "not in a group" so the answer is no, so then we'll create a new group and add this to our list.

Then we keep filling this list with items, until it hits 30 items, and then we simply say "ok, so this group is done, we're no longer in that group". The next line this loop processes will go through that if-statement again adding a fresh group for the next (and following) items.

Comment: I like your code using LINQ and anonymous functions - upvote from me. But it may be difficult for inexperienced users to understand.

Comment: Thank you so much. @ Lasse V. Karlsen